# Como eu restauro uma base de dados a partir de logs no postgres?

Tags: postgresql, log, backup

Eu tenho os logs do banco de dados que eu obtenho através dos comandos `pg_start_backup`e `pg_stop_backup`. Gostaria de saber como faço para restaurar o banco através deles?

Obrigado!

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SO. Qual a versão do PostgreSQL que você está usando?

Comment: Obrigado. Estou usando a versão 9.4.

Answer (score 0):

Eu entendo que você tem um PostgreSQL 9.4 rodando e quer restaurar o banco a partir de um backup feito.

Só para lembrar que o `pg_start_backup` impede que escritas sejam feitas para a pasta onde o banco se encontra, para assim manter a consistência dos dados.

Para realizar um backup e restaurar o mesmo utilizando `pg_start_backup`, você precisa:

```
1 - Execute `select pg_start_backup('label');`
2 - Execute o `rsync` da sua pasta cluster (por padrão na versão 9.4 é a: `/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/` se não me engano)
3 - Execute `select pg_stop_backup();`
4 - Copie todos os logs desde do inicio do `pg_start_backup` até depois que voce tenha executado o `pg_stop_backup`. Quando falo logs me refiro aos wal_files (Você pode checar aonde eles estão sendo armazenados através do `archive_command` no seu `postgresql.conf`).
```

Quando você tiver realizado o `rsync` + a cópia dos wal_files para o novo servidor, você já poderá iniciar o Postgres.

Lembre sempre de acompanhar os logs para saber se deu algum erro.

**EDIT:** UTILIZANDO O `pg_basebackup`

Eu sempre faço backups e restauro meus bancos utilizando o [pg_basebackup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgbasebackup.html).  Na minha opinião ele é melhor e mais fácil de utilizar.